# Magento 2: Cron job not logging value of Product in log file [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, product, cron, custom, crontab

I'm creating new Cron Job.

**app\code\Custom\Module\Cron\MyTask.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Cron;

class MyTask {

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 500));
        $productCollection->load();

        foreach ($productCollection as $products) {
            $this->_logger->debug($products->getName());
            $this->_logger->info($products->getName());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I'm executing through command it's not logging Product Name in `var/log/debug.log` or `var/log/system.log`

Some time it will log, sometime don't

Comment: Does it log anything else? If you replace $products->getName() with another string does it log?

Comment: Nope. Still it's not logging any value by changing to Price or any other

Comment: If its not logging anything, then its an issue with permissions.

Comment: I'm using WAMP on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine now.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

it's saying

**You must run cron twice: the first time to discover tasks to run and the second time to run the tasks themselves.**

So i'm running commands in below order

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
php bin/magento cron:run --group="my_cronjob" // Group Id
php bin/magento cron:run --group="my_cronjob" // Group Id
```

It's logging value now in `var/log/system.log`

Comment: This didn't work for me. It seems like Magento 2 does silencing of errors with Cron modules so it's almost impossible to debug

Comment: @Ankit Shah did you manage to log $product->getFinalPrice() ? I am able to get everything but price.